# Remotely Force Immediate Windows Reboot or Shutdown, without removing AC/DC?

Tags: windows, shutdown, reboot

There are rare occasions when I'm not sitting at the PC, and the Windows power system commands are just not going to work for me.  I need to programmatically force Windows to stop immediately, regardless of the potential for data loss, or risk that the PC might not boot again.  Normally to forcefully stop Windows, I would either hold the power or reset button down for > 10 seconds, remove the battery or AC power.

**Unless absolutely necessary, please explain to users that they should never force a Windows shutdown or reboot. Or, if they do, explain the risks of lost files or failure to boot.**

When would I need this?

- **Windows can't shut down some process** - It ignores any "Quit Windows" commands.
- **System is so busy and slow**, it will (almost) never finish shutting down and:
- ... ---> **The mouse or keyboard is almost frozen** and it takes 5 minutes to even try to initiate power commands.
- ... ---> **Windows will likely take an hour to finish** a coordinated and safe shutdown or reboot.
- **It is physically impossible to press reset or remove AC/DC power from PC, since I'm not at the PC.**
- **Malware appears to be actively encrypting files** or popping up an infinite number of new windows.

**Without writing a new program, how can I force a shutdown or reboot, when the normal powerCFG.exe command options fail?**

Comment: Use the reset button.  Some motherboards still have a reset pin (on the front panel header), although most PC cases omit the front panel button for it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest choice, get the free tiny Wizmo.exe from Steve Gibson's http://www.GRC.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm, put it in your Windows\system folder (so you can execute this from anywhere), then execute one of these commands:

- **Wizmo.exe Shutdown!**
- **Wizmo.exe Reboot!**

I won't list a number of commandline options and programs you could write to do these tasks, when there's a perfectly good choice for most everyone that's free.  Steve Gibson from GRC Research wrote a tiny utility to do a complete job, with more options that you'd ever want.

It also includes the option to force these immediately, simply by adding a "!" to any of the commandline options. Steve says,

> "The shutdown trigger commands list above accept an optional
>   exclamation point "!". For example: "reboot!" (pronounced "Reboot
>   Damit!"). A word of caution: Since the Damit Variations force the
>   requested function to succeed, even if programs or device drivers have
>   refused to give Windows their permission to be shutdown, you should be
>   certain that this is what you want and that any files are safely
>   saved."

For me, these commands are all I need to force a reboot, although I find the other options such as suspend and hibernate saves time.  (Another user's question was removed earlier today and I thought it was a valuable question.)

Comment: This does not appear to support acting on a remote computer.

Comment: I'll do a bit of testing, but seems that, if you are executing this as an admin from the console, it should work.  @Jeff Zeitlin - If from RDP, seems it should also work with admin rights and other admin commands work.

Comment: If the computer is in a state where it's largely unresponsive (per the question), he might not be able to get into the computer via RDP in the first place...

Comment: Agree on getting to this when system is that hung up.  I suspect we'd need a way to hotkey to it, but then have some confirmation so you can't accidentally execute this dangerous command.  I have some thoughts on how to present quite a few of his options in our SnapBack-Apps.com program, vs using a commandline.  Plus, in our app, we do allow non-admins to execute a few safe commands, but with the admin's veto option.

Comment: I've been looking for more info, and I can't find anything that lets you do a "crashdown" remotely - There is a WMI class (`Win32_Shutdown`/`Win32_ShutdownTracker`) that can be used to shutdown a remote computer, but it does a "clean" shutdown, which is not what the querent needs.

Comment: I'll experiment on a PC that I will be restoring an image on, anyway.  Tried Teamviewer when executing?  Also, Meraki.com system management has an ADMIN commandline that should also work.